# Remove duplicate file names in a vector

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes in input a list of files, which are saved in a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> fileNames;
```

The user is completely free to enter any filename (they are taken from `argv`), and if it enters a filename that refers to the same file the program should **ignore** the duplicates.
The problem is that the user can even make the vector having something like this:

```
{
 "myfile1.txt",
 "/path/to/myfile1.txt",
 "/path//to/myfile1.txt"
}
```

Considering I'm calling the program from `/path/to`, the three file names refer to the same file, but they're different strings.

I have to open them with `fopen()` (**not** with `std::ifstream`).

And to check them all the program `fopen()`s all the files before starting its process, so it's not a problem.

Is there an efficient way to remove duplicate file names?

Comment: why don't you just us a set?

Comment: first step would be to normalize them to the same form: full path, replace `//` with `/` and then its a simple task

Comment: [Might help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical). Be aware that the path must exist for it to work and that doing `if (exists) { ... }` is not good enough because it might not exist by the time you use it.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency yet. Start with an algorithm that would get you what you need.

Comment: *"efficient way"* Efficient compared to what and in what sense? Given `argc` is generally not huge anyways, what kind of bottlenecks did you hit so far?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I thought about something like that, but I'm afraid I won't build a "complete" normalization algorithm.

Comment: You can canonicalise pathnames according to simple lexical rules like `//` -> `/`, and even call `realpath()` to expand symlinks, but because mount points allow the same file to be visible via two completely lexically unrelated different paths, be aware the problem you're trying to solve can't *really* be solved.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Trust me, this program can get a huge argc.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I didn't know the existence of `realpath()`! +1 for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::set` rather than a vector to ensure that identical strings are only listed once.

Alternatively you can `std::sort`  (or `std::stable_sort`) the vector and then use `std::unique` combined with `std::erase` to remove duplicates.

As for non-identical strings that refer to the same file; on Linux you could use `realpath(3)` to canonicalize all the paths before adding them to the vector (or set). I don't know an equivalent function on Windows, but I'm sure there is one. Perhaps try searching through msdn.com if you also need this to work on Windows.

Comment: Will the set keep the order of the files the user given?

Comment: @osnapitzkindle No. The set will not preserve that order.

Comment: isn't there an ordered set or something like that like many other languages?

Answer (score 0):

For portable solution you can use `boost::filesystem`:

[boost::equivalent()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#equivalent)

> Returns: true, if sf1 == sf2 and p1 and p2 resolve to the same file
>   system entity, else false.

This way you will have to compare each file vs each other, or you can use [boost::canonical()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical) or [boost::weekly_canonical()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical) to normalize path and use `std::sort` which could be more effective as it does not have to compare each pair.